# Laravel eloquent multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to sort my collection by date and then sort the rows that have the same date by it's distance.

I have done the same process when i was working with status and distance it was easier because i know the status values that i want to sort the collection by, now with dates i can't fix it's values.

Here's my work with status :

```
if($result){
        if($data['status'] == true){
            $result = $result->sortBy('listing.status')->values();

            if($sqlDistance != null){
                $res = $result->where('distance_km', '!=', null);

                $resNull = $result->where('distance_km', '=', null)->all();

                $statusNotPlanned = $res->where('listing.status', 0)->sortBy('distance_km')->values()->all();
                $statusPlanned = $res->where('listing.status', 1)->sortBy('distance_km')->values()->all();
                $statusDone = $res->where('listing.status', 2)->sortBy('distance_km')->values()->all();

                $res = array_merge($statusNotPlanned, $statusPlanned, $statusDone);
                $result = array_merge($res, $resNull);
            }

            return response()->json(['status' => 200,'type' => 'status', 'data' => $data, 'events' => (is_object($result)) ? array_slice($result->toArray(),$data['offset']*10,10) : array_slice($result,$data['offset']*10,10), 'cities' => $cities]);
        }
```

Now i need to do the same but with date instead of status :

Here's where i am now :

```
 elseif($data['date'] == true ) {
            $result = $result->sortBy('date_end')->values();

            $res = $result->where('date_end', '!=', null)->all();
            $resNull = $result->where('date_end', '=', null)->all();
            $result = array_merge($res, $resNull);

            return response()->json(['status' => 200,'type' => 'date', 'data' => $data, 'events' => (is_object($result)) ? array_slice($result->toArray(),$data['offset']*10,10) : array_slice($result,$data['offset']*10,10), 'cities' => $cities]);
        }
```

This is my current output :

```
    {
    date_end : 12/07/2018,
    distance : 320km

    },
   {
  date_end : 12/08/2018,
  distance : 110km

   },
   {
  date_end : 12/08/2018,
  distance : 100km

    },
   {
    date_end : 12/08/2018,
   distance : 120km

   },
    {
    date_end : 12/09/2018,
    distance : 480km

    }
```

This is the desired output :

```
   {
  date_end : 12/07/2018,
  distance : 320km

    },
     {
    date_end : 12/08/2018,
    distance : 100km

    },
    {
    date_end : 12/08/2018,
    distance : 110km

    },
    {
   date_end : 12/08/2018,
   distance : 120km

},
{
  date_end : 12/09/2018,
  distance : 480km

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on this Github [issue](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11#issuecomment-432976494) suggested the following:

```
$result->sortBy(function($item) {
      return [$item->date_end, $item->distance_km];
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your method returns exactly the same data as what i already did, it does not take in consideration the rows that have the same $date_end value and sort them by distance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you could add example input and output results it could help. For example, show us your data before, the results you're getting and the results you're expecting.

Comment: It does not works for me because the date_end attribute contains hours and minutes, i need to make the sort only by days.Thank you for your replies